# Django models - html/render attribute?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I use the same models in many different templates and tables. I'm looking for a way to tell Django how to render those objects in templates so I don't have to write the same `html` again and again.

For example model Url - when I want to display it inside a template or table, I have to write (sometimes much more):

```
<a href="{{ url.url }}">{{ url.site.name }}</a>
```

which renders:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">Stackoverflow.com</a>
```

It would be better if I could just do something like:

```
{{ url }} # url is Url model object
```

I think that I can add methods like `def render_object(self)` like this:

```
def render_object(self):
    return mark_safe("""<a href="{}">{}</a>""".format(self.url,self.site.name))
```

and in templates:

```
{{ url.render_object }}
```

but I'm curious if it is there some built in function. As far as I know `__unicode__(self)` would do the work but it would mess admin and shell display names.

Comment: Did you check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/ ?

Comment: Super interesting question. I have been wondering the same thing and started exploring solutions based on a abstract base classes (for the render method), data class (for easy creation of classes that hold data needed in the template) and a template tag (to invoke the objects render method and allow the context to be extended). This is very work in progress, but take a look here: https://github.com/tbrlpld/lpld-io/pull/189/files#diff-e591d5553677563a212e0014b907981748de8a3453866f0c219383d691fa2131

Answer (score 0):

Add custom template tag `my_tags.py` like `render_url` and then in your template load that template tag (`{% load my_tags %}`) and send url object to it: `{% render_url url %}`. You can use html template in your tag or just make result as a string and return it. Check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/) for details.